# awk - print data before RS, same line

Tags: awk

I have an output which I am piping to awk and found a good RS string at the end of some lines.
But when I define the trailing string as RS, awk just removes the whole line content. I want the data up to the RS string preserved and only the RS removed from the line.

Example input for awk:

```
data data data RS_STRING
data SEARCHED_STRING data data
data data

data data data RS_STRING
data data data
data data

data data data RS_STRING
data SEARCHED_STRING data data
data data
```

Desired output from awk:

```
data data data
data SEARCHED_STRING data data
data data

data data data
data SEARCHED_STRING data data
data data
```

My current awk syntax is:

```
awk '/SEARCHED_STRING/' RS = "RS_STRING"
```

...and I get:

```
data SEARCHED_STRING data data
data data


data SEARCHED_STRING data data
data data
```

As you can see by defining RS_STRING as RS, awk strips all the data preceding the RS, contained in that line.

I've been searching for a solution for the past three days but have yet to find one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. RS is the record (line) separator; were you thinking perhaps that you'd found a good field separator?  If you mean record separator, then the sample data has just 3 records, the third not terminated (the material before the first RS STRING, the material between the two markers, and the material after the second marker).  What exactly is the RS string that you're using?  How exactly are you setting the RS?

Comment: The issue I'm having, as stated, is with setting a RS that is not at the very beginning of a line. When I set a RS at the beginning of a line, it gets stripped from that line and the data after RS from that line remains intact. But if the RS is located anywhere else within the line, everything up to the defined RS gets deleted. I want to preserve that data. The example is just there to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try sed and replace RS STRING with null. Sample: sed 's/RS STRING//'

Comment: But RS is what marks the 'end of line'...

Comment: I just edited my original post to better illustrate what my issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk with empty line as record separator

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="RS_STRING"}
    /SEARCHED_STRING/{$1=$1;print $0 ORS}'  file
```

If there are no blank lines between records, and RS_STRING is always in first line of record, then try this:

```
awk '/RS_STRING/{i++}{a[i]=a[i]==""?$0:a[i]RS $0}
    END{for (j=1;j<=i;j++) if (a[j]~/SEARCHED_STRING/) print a[j]}' file
```

Comment: Since you've already have a BEGIN block, might as well add `ORS="\n\n"` and remove the ORS from the print statement.

Comment: @glennjackman Why? This works, and `ORS` is 7 character  less than `ORS="\n\n"`.  I do normally not use `BEGIN` block if not needed and add variable behind expression to save the `-v` give it like this `awk '/SEARCHED_STRING/ {$1=$1;print $0 ORS}' RS="" FS="RS_STRING" file`

Comment: Is there a way to modify this awk syntax in order to have RS="RS_STRING" instead of ""? I ask this because my input doesn't necessarily have blank lines between records, RS cannot be anything else except for RS_STRING in order to have the desired output.

Comment: how to group the sections, if no blank lines? Any rules? Do you mean if I see RS_STRING, that means the section will start from this line?

Comment: Thank you, the second solution worked as intended. Quite a complicated syntax, will try to decipher it.

Answer (score 1):

a non-awk answer

```
perl -00 -ne '/SEARCHED_STRING/ and do {s/RS_STRING//g; print}'
```

Search for paragraphs with the search string and remove the "rs" string.

Comment: Thank you, this solution produced the intended results. Could you please explain the syntax? I am curious how it manages to correctly separate the records. I can only identify the searching pattern (SEARCHED_STRING) and the substitution of the RS_STRING with blank. But how does it know that the RS_STRING is my record separator?

Comment: Found this in Perl documentation: "The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode. Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose." Unfortunately I don't understand it.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the above solution in order to specifically have the records separated by the RS_STRING? My input doesn't necessarily have blank lines between records so when I tested the command on my live data it included some bits of information that normally would have been stripped off if the RS was defined by RS_STRING. Thank you.

Comment: Just read through Perl's documentation: "Remember: the value of $/ is a string, not a regex. awk has to be better for something. :-)" This means that if I want to define the RS with a regex, I need to return to awk :(

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
echo "ab RS_STRING cd" | awk '{print "NR="NR ": \""$0"\""}' RS="RS_STRING"
```

gives output

```
NR=1: "ab "
NR=2: " cd
"
```

as you see, no parts are stripped off except the string `"RS_STRING"`..